# insert date from neighbor entry

Tags: oracle

Table has columns for `issue_date`, `part_num` and `date_received`.

If an  `issue_date` is `null`, I want to select `issue_date` of `part_num + 1` (the next part number), and insert it in the `issue_date` column of the part with no issue date.

`part_num` is sequential.

What sql statement would select then insert the appropriate issue date?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Figured it out with a little self join statement.. thank you delete if you wish!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
update t
set t.issue_date = (select issue_date 
                       from t t1 
                      where t1.part_num = t.part_num+1)
where t.issue_date is null
```

But, if the next part number also doesn't have issue_date, this will ramain null's in issue_date. To solve this problem you can change query to this one (if it's suitable for your application):

```
update t
set t.issue_date = (select min(issue_date)
                       from t t1 
                      where t1.part_num > t.part_num)
where t.issue_date is null
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I had thought of the next still null issue, and you solved it most elegantly.